# is it possible to share cookies between subdomains

Tags: session, cookies

Is it possible to share cookies between the following subdomains??

```
sharepoint.server.com   AND     data.server.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the cookie's domain in your header

`Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.mydomain.com`

the `.` in front of the URL makes the cookie available throughout any subdomain.

---

> In [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109), a domain without a leading dot meant that it could not be used on subdomains, and only a leading dot (`.mydomain.com`) would allow it to be used across subdomains.

[source and more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/1451422)

---

## **UPDATE**

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives), leading dots are no longer required to include subdomains. Subdomains are now included within the domain declaration.

Comment: What if the subdomains want to share the session between them, but not with the www subdomain? Haven't found a way at the moment :(

Comment: Looks like this is no longer true. MDN says "Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names are ignored. If a domain is specified, subdomains are always included."  -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives

Answer (score 2):

For simple working with cookie I'm using [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) and by using this library with the below code:

```js
Cookie.set('key', 'value', { domain: '.example-domain.com' })
```

All subdomains and also base domain can share cookie between eachother