# Why can't I access this cookie via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

My server sends a `locale` cookie to the frontend which the backend determines from the client's accept language header. When I run the backend and frontend on `localhost`, I'm able to access the `locale` cookie in the javascript in `document.cookie` on the browser. It's also visible in chrome devtools (Application Tab-> Cookies).

But when I run the backend and frontend remotely over https, I cannot access the cookie in the javascript on the browser. Nor is it visible in devtools (Application Tab-> Cookies).

```js
document.cookie // no locale cookie in javascript devtools console
"_ga=somevalue; _gid=somevalue; __stripe_mid=somevalue; __stripe_sid=somevalue"
```

But I can see the `locale` cookie in the response's `Set-Cookie` header and in `chrome://settings/cookies/`.

Response:

> Set-Cookie: locale=%7B%22locale%22%3A%22en-US%22%2C%22countryCode%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22languageCode%22%3A%22en%22%7D; Max-Age=1617632; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 24 Apr 2021 07:34:03 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None

`chrome://settings/cookies/`:

> **Name**: locale 
> **Content**
> : %7B%22locale%22%3A%22en-US%22%2C%22countryCode%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22languageCode%22%3A%22en%22%7D 
> **Domain**: mydomain.herokuapp.com 
> **Path**: / 
> **Send for**: Secure connections only 
> **Accessible to script**: Yes 
> **Created**: Monday, April 5, 2021 at 9:25:27 AM 
> **Expires**: Saturday, April 24, 2021 at 2:45:56 AM

I know you cannot access HTTP only cookies in javascript, but it's not an HTTP only cookie. It is set to secure but that shouldn't matter *"Cookies with this attribute can still be read/modified with access to the client's hard disk, or from JavaScript if the HttpOnly cookie attribute is not set."*[src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie). It is also a cross origin cookie, my backend is running on `mydomain.herokuapp.com` and my frontend on `mydomain.netlify.app`.

What would cause this cookie to not be accessible by javascript?

Comment: There's no such thing as cross-origin cookies. You can't set a cookie in a different domain.

Comment: Thanks. I switched it to the same domain now, but different subdomains and it's still not working. Shouldn't it work across different subdomains?

Comment: You can only set cookies in the same domain or a parent domain. Not across subdomains.

Comment: I was able to make it work with different subdomains by setting the domain to `mydomain.com` after reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354962/is-it-possible-to-share-cookies-between-subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the frontend can only read the cookie by javascript if the cookie is set to the domain of the frontend app. But the backend and frontend were on totally different domains. And since the backend was on a totally different domain, it cannot set on a cookie on the frontend domain. So I moved them to subdomains of the same domain- frontend.mydomain.com and backend.mydomain.com. Then I set the cookie to `mydomain.com` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354962/is-it-possible-to-share-cookies-between-subdomains#answer-32355083).

```
    res.cookie('locale', JSON.stringify(localeObj), {
      maxAge: new Date() * 0.001 + 300,
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
      secure: true,
      sameSite:'none',
    });
```